# Match a string and the 5 characters before and after

Tags: regex

I need to match the string `one` or `two` and the 5 characters before and after

with the following text in input

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy one text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen two book. It has survived not
>   only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

the output should be

- ummy one text
- imen two book

the regex should works with the [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method in ruby

Comment: How did you get 2,000 experience points in this site... without learning that you have to at least try your homework questions before posting them?

Comment: I agree with @PP. I don't realize how do you obtain that reputation. You aren't showing anything, even a try of solve this by yourself.

Comment: people, please - not every one knows how to handle regex. it might not be his field. you can give a more constructive comment, such as a reference to a regex manual rather than taunting the guy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
.{5}(?:one|two).{5}
```

If you want word boundaries then:

```
.{5}\b(?:one|two)\b.{5}
```

#### Live Demo (Ruby): http://www.rubular.com/r/AcDOFxMx31

Comment: Just to clarify, the `?` is the char that regex uses to tell it to look for the characters before the pattern, the number of chars looked for is denoted by the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

don't know the ruby syntax, but in general, the following should work:

```
 .....(one|two).....
```

in some languages, you can do something like that

```
   .{5}(one|two).{5}
```

but this is not as confirmed as the previous line

in order to output the entire selection you'll need to have braces around all the selection and pick the second result (the regular expression will set the first find as one\two and the second as the finding) e.g.

```
 (.....(one|two)....)
```

$1 = "one"
$2 = " bla one bla "

edit 1 = example
edit 2 = typos